# Protect sharing for another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a new protection for excel workbook as you know excel's protection is very weak.
Now I need to set protection for sharing and this would be done for another workbook not the activeworkbook

Suppose the code is in Test.xlsm and I need to protect the closed workbook Sample.xlm
This is the code that I created

```
Dim wb As Workbook

Sub DoProtectionTask()
    Dim sPath As String
    sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Sample.xlsm"
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sPath)
    ProtectSharing True, "123", "456"
    wb.Close True
End Sub

Private Sub ProtectSharing(ByVal b As Boolean, ByVal sPass1 As String, ByVal sPass2 As String)
    Dim x
    If b Then
        On Error GoTo Skipper
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            wb.ProtectSharing Password:=sPass1, SharingPassword:=sPass2
Skipper:
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    Else
        x = InputBox("Enter Admin Password")
        If x <> sPass1 Then MsgBox "Invalid Password. Contact The Workbook Owner", vbExclamation: Exit Sub
        wb.UnProtectSharing sPass1
    End If
End Sub
```

It works and errors for the code, but when opening the Sample.xlsm after running the code, I didn't find the workbook protected from sharing. Although this method works on ThisWorbook or ActiveWorkbook

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that i well understood, but I thing this code `wb.UnProtectSharing sPass1` should look like: `wb.UnProtectSharing sPass2`

all code:

```
Dim wb As Workbook

Sub DoProtectionTask()
    Dim sPath As String
    sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Sample.xlsm"
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sPath)
    ProtectSharing True, "123", "456"
    wb.Close True
End Sub

Private Sub ProtectSharing(ByVal b As Boolean, ByVal sPass1 As String, ByVal sPass2 As String)
    Dim x
    If b Then
        On Error GoTo Skipper
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            wb.ProtectSharing Password:=sPass1, SharingPassword:=sPass2
Skipper:
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    Else
        x = InputBox("Enter Admin Password")
        If x <> sPass1 Then MsgBox "Invalid Password. Contact The Workbook Owner", vbExclamation: Exit Sub
        wb.UnProtectSharing sPass2
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. The problem is protecting by share not unprotecting.